# Is Honey Senpai a Shota?

Tags: terminology, ouran-high-school-host-club

If so, then what would be the opposite of Honey Senpai's character? Like between the ages of 40 years an up?

I read it one time when I was looking at Japanese Shoujo Manga, but I do remember encountering it on the site Manga Here.

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to [Mitsukuni "Honey" Haninozuka](http://ouran.wikia.com/wiki/Mitsukuni_%22Honey%22_Haninozuka) from Ouran High Host Club in which case Renge indicated he is the Boy Lolita or Shota archtype a couple of times

Answer (score -2, accepted):

お爺さん or 叔父さん？

[image]

Miryoku-tekina toshiue no otoko?

[image]

An attractive older man?

[image]

Since you mentioned between the ages of 40 years an up and were asking for a term that represents the opposite of Honey Senpai's (Shota) character...

[image]

Then that would have to be an Older Man = Oji-san (uncle) or Ojiisan (old man).

[image]

It can also be used as a slightly impolite way to address a middle aged man.

[image]

If you have your doubts of such a genre existing, note that not all women prefer Shotas or Bishonens.

[image]

There is such a thing as an "Ojisan Paradise."

[image]

Comment: this question doesn't really answer the question, all it does is take a phrase and runs it through [google translate](https://translate.google.com.au/#auto/ja/An%20attractive%20older%20man). it would be good if you can back up your answer with some facts whether this term is actually used within the fandom/culture

Comment: There's your proof of the term actually being used within the fandom/culture of the anime world.

Comment: (づ￣ ³￣)づ ARIGATO!

Comment: "魅力的な年上の男", while valid Japanese, is not a common collocation by any means, with only 8 hits on Google and 0 results in BCCWJ Shonagon. This answer is remarkably unconvincing, so I have downvoted it.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion, but the fact of the matter is that the person asking it was satisfied enough with my answer to award it the best out of the two. She even said thank you, honestly you really shouldn't be making these things about yourself since the site was made specifically to answer questions any users may have regarding Anime. She was asking what the opposite term of a Shota was, and I gave her Ojisan/Oji-san as an answer. (  ^ u ^)/